# How to mock exception types in "Throws" and "ThrowsAsync"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, xunit, fluent-assertions

I would like to write one unit test for a set of different exception types. My common approach is to use InlineAutoMoqData for a certain set of test inputs. This works fine for values but I cannot get it working for types.

Below you can find my idea / wished solution:

```
[Theory]
[InlineAutoMockData(typeOf(HttpRequestException)] 
[InlineAutoMockData(typeOf(InvalidOperationException)] 
public async void MyTestFunction_Should_HandleExceptions(Type exceptionType, Mock<HttpClient> clientMock)
{
    // Arrange
    var cut = CreateCut();
    clientMock.Setup(c => c.SendAsync()).ThrowsAsync(new Exception()); // here I want to  create a generic Exception dependend on the exceptionType instead of "new Exception"

   // Act
   var result = cut.DoSomething();
   
   // Assert
   result.Should().BeTrue();
}
```

I could add a switch case checking "exceptionType" and moq the client dependend on it. This solution works but does not feel "right". I think there has to be a more elegant solution to it.

Comment: Could you please share with us the code that you are testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Activator` to create an object from a type.

```
clientMock.Setup(c => 
   c.SendAsync()).ThrowsAsync((Exception) Activator.CreateInstance(exceptionType));
```

Answer (score 3):

xUnit supports generic parameters.
So you should be able to do something like this.

```cs
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(Exceptions))]
#pragma warning disable xUnit1026 // Theory methods should use all of their parameters
public async Task MyTestFunction_Should_HandleExceptions<TException>(TException _, Mock<HttpClient> clientMock)
#pragma warning restore xUnit1026 // Theory methods should use all of their parameters
    where TException : Exception, new()
{
    // Arrange
    var cut = CreateCut();
    clientMock.Setup(c => c.SendAsync()).Throws<TException>();


    // Act
    var result = cut.DoSomething();

    // Assert
    result.Should().BeTrue();
}

public static TheoryData<Exception> Exceptions() => new()
{
    new HttpRequestException(),
    new InvalidOperationException()
};
```

Since I couldn't run your snippet, here's the code I used to verify that the idea above worked.

```cs
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(Exceptions))]
#pragma warning disable xUnit1026 // Theory methods should use all of their parameters
public async Task MyTestFunction_Should_HandleExceptions<TException>(TException _)
#pragma warning restore xUnit1026 // Theory methods should use all of their parameters
    where TException : Exception, new()
{
    // Arrange
    var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
    handlerMock
        .Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
            "SendAsync",
            ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
            ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
        )
        .Throws<TException>();

    var client = new HttpClient(handlerMock.Object)
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://test.com/")
    };
    var cut = new Cut(client);

    // Act
    var result = await cut.DoSomething();

    // Assert
    result.Should().BeTrue();
}

public static TheoryData<Exception> Exceptions() => new()
{
    new HttpRequestException(),
    new InvalidOperationException()
};

private class Cut
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public Cut(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<bool> DoSomething()
    {
        var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage());
        return result.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `[ClassData]` instead. See [this article](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/#using-a-dedicated-data-class-with-classdata-) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either use reflection as already suggested, or place the test in an abstract generic class, where the type parameter is the exception type, and then add a derived class for each exception type you wish to test. Neither solution is very elegant, unfortunately.